# What does "twist" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From the poem ["The Free-Selector's Daughter"](http://www.ironbarkresources.com/henrylawson/FreeSelectorsDaughter.html) (emphasis mine)

> **I broke my pipe and burnt my twist**,
>   And washed my mouth with water;
>   I had a shave before I kissed
>   The free-selector's daughter.

In this context, what would **twist** mean?

Comment: Twist=Tobacco, here

Comment: To expand on @NVZ's comment, it's a reference to chewing tobacco, specifically, which is twisted into a crude "rope" before selling, hence "twist of tobacco".

Comment: Fascinating! I have never heard of that use of twist before. Do you know how it originated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the **tobacco pipe** mentioned here. — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tobacco+pipe)

> *noun* a tube with a small bowl at one end; used for smoking tobacco

**Twist**, refers to tobacco. — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist)

> 1.d. tobacco leaves twisted into a thick roll

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewing_tobacco#Types

Comment: So would the pipe then refer to a smoking pipe?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes, especially since "twist" tobacco is suitable for chewing *or* smoking in a pipe (according to that wikipedia page).

Comment: So what would "I broke my pipe" mean?

Comment: @Oreo I suppose, he literally broke the pipe and burnt away the tobacco instead of smoking them, in order to kiss the girl. He even shaved for the kiss. It could also mean something different, but discussing lyric interpretation here will be off-topic.